# Mean values of position and momentum given a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I've never done a similar problem before.
A particle in a one-dimensional system, with mass $m$, is described at time $t=0$ by the wave function
$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<-a\\1+\dfrac{x}{a}&-a<x<0\\1-\dfrac{x}{a}&0<x<a\\0&x>a \end{cases}$$
I have to find:

1. The mean value of the position at time $t$ (not subject to any force).
2. The mean value of the momentum and of the position at time $t$ if the particle is subject to a constant force $F$.
3. The wave function at time $t$ (not subject to any force).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 3):

The initial wavefunction is the "triangle function" and the first step is to find its Fourier transform.
\begin{equation}
\psi(x) = a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{sinc}^2 \left ( \frac{k}{2\pi a} \right ) e^{ikx} \frac{dk}{2\pi}
\end{equation}
This expresses the initial state in a basis of plane waves which are energy eigenstates when the potential is zero. Therefore each one evolves by a pure phase so we have
\begin{align}
\Psi(x, t) = \psi(x) = a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{sinc}^2 \left ( \frac{k}{2\pi a} \right ) e^{-i E_k t / \hbar} e^{ikx} \frac{dk}{2\pi}
\end{align}
where the energies are given by
\begin{equation}
E_k = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}.
\end{equation}
The mean position and momenta can now be found by the standard formulae
\begin{align}
\langle x(t) \rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \left | \Psi(x, t) \right |^2 dx \\
\langle p(t) \rangle &= -i \hbar \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi^*(x, t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Psi(x, t) dx
\end{align}
but consider why they asked you to find these mean values *before* the wavefunction itself. The initial wavefunction is symmetric about the origin, i.e. $\psi(x) = \psi(-x)$ and the (free) Hamiltonian causing it to evolve is symmetric as well. So can you notice the values of the above integrals before actually doing them?

For the second part, it helps to know that force and potential are related by
\begin{equation}
F = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} V(x)
\end{equation}
meaning you have $V(x) = -Fx$. This in principle allows you to find $\Psi(x, t)$ again but the calculation would need to involve eigenfunctions of the new Hamiltonian which are Airy functions instead of plane waves. So I think the idea here is to use the fact that "classical intuition" holds for the mean values. The precise statement of this is [Ehrenfest's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) which is good to read about if it's unfamiliar.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you for answering me.
Your explanation was clear, but my main problem now is understanding how you've determined the wave function at time t = 0. I tried to write the wave function as a combination of sine ad cosine using boundary conditions in x = a, -a, 0, but I don't get a sinc. Can you kindly explain me your method?

Comment: I honestly just looked up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform lines 203 and 204. If you are okay with the fact that the rectangular function Fourier transforms to a single $\mathrm{sinc}(k)$ then the triangle version follows from the convolution theorem. But I don't know off the top of my head what the tricks are for doing these integrals.

Comment: copy, thank you!